# Weird copy and paste behaviour

Tags: front-end

If I select and copy some text from a `Text`-cell, say,

```
Cell["Test", "Text"]
```

and paste this somewhere (like here) I get:

```
T\
e\
s\
t
```

I use Win 10 with MMA 10.2 or 10.3.1. The behaviour also appears in other cell types like `Subsection` but not in `Input` cells.

Why is that and what could I do about it?

Comment: Works fine on my Mac. Have you tried `Edit | Copy As | Plain Text`?

Comment: Ok, that helps. Thanks. I would still like to know why `ctrl+c` does not work and if one can fix this.

Comment: On my Mac you just need to add a `Shift`, i.e.,  `Command+Shift+C`. This shortcut is shown on the menu bar next to the `Plain Text`.

Comment: Clearing the Mathematica preference files solves this problem. Instructions can be found here: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464